# Method some() doesn't work as expected in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular app and I want to add follow/unfollow functionality for users. I'm trying to add isFollowed flag, so I will be able to know if user is followed or no, and depending on that I will show 2 different buttons: **Follow** and **Unfollow**. I'm using `some()` method for this purposes but it doesn't work. It shows me that isFollowed flag is `undefined` although it should show `true` or `false`. I don't understand where the problem is, here is my HTML relevant part:

```
<button *ngIf="!isFollowing; else unfollowBtn" class="btn" id="btn-follow" (click)="follow(id)">Follow </button>
<ng-template #unfollowBtn><button class="btn" id="btn-follow" (click)="unFollow(id)">Unfollow</button></ng-template>
```

TS component relevant part:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { AuthenticationService } from '@services/auth.service';
import { FollowersService } from '@services/followers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user;
  id;
  followers;
  isFollowing: boolean;

  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private followersService: FollowersService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.authenticationService.getSpecUser(this.id).subscribe(
      (info => {
        this.user = info;
      })
    );
    this.followersService.getFollowing().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.followers = data;
        this.isFollowing = this.followers.some(d => d.id == this.user.id);
      }
    );
  }

  follow(id) {
    console.log('follow btn');
    this.followersService.follow(id).subscribe(
      (data => console.log(data))
    )
    this.isFollowing = true;
  }

  unFollow(id) {
    console.log('unFollow btn');
    this.followersService.unFollow(id).subscribe(
      (data => console.log(data))
    )
    this.isFollowing = false;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type is `followers`? Is it an Array?

Comment: are you sure data is not undefined 

Comment: have you confirmed that `this.user.id` has the value you expect. and that `data` also has the values you expect?

Comment: What does `Array.isArray(followers)` return?

Comment: You make two asynchronous calls. `this.user` will only be initialized if `getSpecUser` is finished before `getFollowing`.

Comment: ```followers``` is an Array, data is not ```undefined``` I've checked in console, I've confimed that I receive the values I'm expecting

Comment: @Ivar should I place one call into another?

Comment: That would be one option to ensure that `this.user` is always defined. But in that case the second call can't start before the first one is completed. Ultimately you'd want something like [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) so that both calls can be made simultaneously and the `this.isFollowing` is initialized once both are finished. But I'm not too familiar with Observables (which is used here instead of Promises), so I can't really tell you how to implement that in this case.

Comment: If you want it called everytime and to make sure `this.user` is populated. Then you could stack the subscription inside one another .this.authenticationService.getSpecUser(this.id).subscribe(
      (info => {
        this.user = info;                        
       this.followersService.getFollowing().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.followers = data;
        this.isFollowing = this.followers.some(d => d.id == this.user.id);
      }
    );
      })
    );

Answer (score 0):

If you want it called everytime and to make sure `this.user` is populated. Then you could use a forkJoin

```
forkJoin(
    this.authenticationService.getSpecUser(this.id),
    this.followersService.getFollowing()
  ).pipe(
    map(([info, data]) => {
      // forkJoin returns an array of values, here we map those values to the objects
      this.user = info; 
      this.followers = data;                               
      this.isFollowing = this.followers.some(d => d.id == this.user.id);
    })
  );
```

Not tested this because I didn't have time. If you make a StackBlitz we could see it in action and try from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: forkJoin is the correct answer here. nested subscribes should be avoided always.

Comment: @bryan60 I agree. Not even sure what I was thinking.